# Obtain match strings in a specific column

Tags: shell, awk

INPUT:

```
FRUIT1|FRUIT2|COLORS
apple|orange|color1=red;color2=orange;color3=yellow
grapes|apple|color4=purple
pineapple|pomelo|color1=red;color3=orange
orange|apple|color1=red;color2=orange;color3=yellow;color4=purple
```

Reference:

```
color1
color3
color4
```

I have an input file and reference above.
Basically, I want to match the 3rd or COLORS column with the list of strings under references and get the string after match and before ';'. 
The output would be the first two columns (FRUIT1 and FRUIT2) and the matching result.

OUTPUT

```
apple|orange|red|yellow|
grapes|apple|||purple
pineapple|pomelo|red|orange|
orange|apple|red|yellow|purple
```

**doesn't need to have a header

I have tried looping through the file and matching the references through grep but I'm looking for a code that can be generic.

```
cat input.txt | while read line
do

color1=$(echo "$line" | grep -o -P '(?<=color1=).*?(?=;)')
color3=$(echo "$line" | grep -o -P '(?<=color3=).*?(?=;)')
color4=$(echo "$line" | grep -o -P '(?<=color4=).*?(?=;)')

echo $line| awk -F"|" -v color1=${color1} -v color3=${color3} -v color4=${color4} '{print $1"|"$2"|"color1"|"color3"|"color4}'

done
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt so far.

Comment: You want to print blanks @user10649674 for color values which are NOT found in Input_file right? Because your expected output is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output doesn't look clear so considering that you need to print `|` in case any color value NOT found in reference file and your header requirement is also not clear.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($3,array,"[=;]")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
    if(array[i] in a){
      val=val?val OFS array[i+1]:array[i+1]
    }
    else{
      val=val?val OFS "|":"|"
    }
  }
  print $1,$2,val
  val=""
}
' reference  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
FRUIT1|FRUIT2|COLORS
apple|orange|red|||yellow
grapes|apple|purple
pineapple|pomelo|red|orange
orange|apple|red|||yellow|purple
```

Comment: This is really what I'm looking for. The header isn't needed.  I apologize for the unclear question. Thank you!

Comment: @user10649674, your welcome, keep learning, keep posting on this great site SO.